# alien race gives us the ultimate weapon "for good and evil" which works both ways - probably 1950s

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, weapon

In this movie, an alien race gives mankind an "ultimate weapon". It's a small capsule-shaped thing which, when activated, kills everybody within some large radius. One scientist offers to test it on a remote island, as I remember, and remembers that the aliens said it was for "good and evil". The scientist thinks the "and" must be important. He inspects the gadget closely, and sees a small pin in one end of the capsule, and a small hole in the other end. He takes the pin out, puts it in the other end, and when activated the gadget now only kills evil-doers. Problem solved.

Comment: The punchline is that the weapon still kills everyone.

Comment: This is similar to the movie, **Absolutely Anything**, but that was made on the 12 August, 2015.

Comment: Definitely a 50s movie. ;) “All known enemies of human freedom.”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the movie you are seeking is: *[The 27th Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_27th_Day)* from 1957.

Comment: That's it. Still haven't found a copy of the movie, but most of my ageing brain cells agree; thanks.

Comment: Seeing the movie confirms it is what I was looking for. Pre-CGI, but still enjoyable.