# Need the name of an old classic SFF movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

What is the name of this old movie where some scientists are given a device with two vials by an Alien world, which apparently have the the power to rid evil in the world. The last 2 vials are set off with the scientist saying

> “power of life AND death”

... not life OR death.

Comment: *How* old? 10 years ago, 50 years ago?

Comment: I know someone who said, around ten years ago, that he likes old sci-fi movies. Like Spaceballs. And he was young enough to be serious.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27749/alien-race-gives-us-the-ultimate-weapon-for-good-and-evil-which-works-both-way

Answer (score 5):

Though it is not actually just scientists to whom the vials are given, I believe the movie you are seeking is: "The 27th Day" from 1957. Too, it is a bit older than your friend might have mentioned since it was in B&W.

In this case it is actually 5 capsules given to individuals around the world.

"Five individuals from five nations, including the "Superpowers," USA, USSR, and China, suddenly find themselves on an alien spacecraft. An alien gives each a container holding capsules. No power on earth can open a given container except a mental command from the person to whom it is given. Each person has been provided with ***the power of life and death.*** Any of these individuals has the capability to instantaneously launch the capsules to whatever coordinates he/she chooses, and each capsule will then eradicate all human life within a 3,000-mile radius of its designated location. "

An excerpt from Wiki is listed below which might help confirm this is the moview of which you are thinking. In particular as part of the spoiler portion there is a "decode" of the capsules which matches your description of the statement the "Power of Life AND Death" (vs. Or)

> "Five people, Englishwoman Evelyn Wingate, American reporter Jonathan Clark, Chinese peasant Su Tan, German physicist Klaus Bechner, and Soviet soldier Ivan Godofsky, are randomly transported to an alien spacecraft in Earth orbit. There, they are met by a humanoid referring to himself only as "The Alien" (Arnold Moss), who explains that he is the representative of a world orbiting a sun about to go Nova. Needing a new world to inhabit within the next 35 days, yet prohibited by their moral code from killing intelligent life, The Alien provides each of the five with sets of three capsules in a clear, round, hand-held case. Each capsule is capable of destroying all human life within a 3,000-mile diameter, with the expectation that humanity will use all the capsules, obliterating itself, leaving the Earth free for alien colonization. The capsules' clear containers can only be opened by the thought waves of the person to whom they were given. Once out in the open, the capsules inside can then be used by anyone, but only during the next 27 days, after which they become inert."

Towards the end of the story we learn:

> On board a U. S. destroyer being used as a deterrent against the Soviet capsules being used against America, Bechner, Clark, and Eve discuss their concerns that the Soviets will use them at the last minute, avoiding retaliation. Determined to find another way, Bechner studies the remaining capsules and discovers an imprinted mathematical code on them. As the Soviet general prepares to use the capsules from a balcony, Godofsky rushes him, and the capsules fall to the ground two stories below. At the very same moment, Bechner simultaneously launches his remaining capsules and the ones from Clark's container. He has deciphered the hidden code and discovered that the capsules can be programmed. The world is then blanketed with a high-pitched sonic wave that kills every "known enemy of human freedom".

And then at the very end:

> In the aftermath, at an undisclosed later time, a now united humanity invites the aliens to coexist peacefully, sharing the Earth. It turns out, however, to have all been a test of mankind's character. The Alien's sun is quite stable. He in turn invites the people of Earth to join the Galactic Federation, having now passed its crucial test.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_27th_Day