# I'm looking for the title of a black and white science fiction film from the 50's or 60's

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think the world was on the edge of war.

Alien character has a small, compact, oval-shaped, translucent device that fits in the palm of your hand. It opens with the power of the mind of the person that holds it. Inside are 4 or 5 pill, elongated ovals,like capsules. Using the mind you can send them to any latitude/longitude you imagine. They stop the war by getting rid of all of the bad guys/people.

This is the best I have of a fragmented memory... except to say I love the film and never forgot it... except for the title!

Comment: if it is *The 27th Day*, then it's a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27749/alien-race-gives-us-the-ultimate-weapon-for-good-and-evil-which-works-both-way/29124#29124

Answer (score 10):

I think this is *[The 27th Day](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050085/?ref_=adv_li_tt)* (1957).  From the IMDB plot summary

> Five individuals from five nations, including the "Superpowers," USA, USSR, and China, suddenly find themselves on an alien spacecraft. An alien gives each a container holding capsules. No power on earth can open a given container except a mental command from the person to whom it is given. Each person has been provided with the power of life and death. Any of these individuals has the capability to instantaneously launch the capsules to whatever coordinates he/she chooses, and each capsule will then eradicate all human life within a 3,000-mile radius of its designated location.